# Exported runnable jar not working because java.net.URL.toString() is null?

Tags: java, selenium, maven, spotify, executable-jar

I have been working on a program and I finally decided to try to export it and run it, so I began using Launch4j to create a jar wrapper. Whenever I try to run it, either through Launch4j or using a .bat file, it does not start.

In Eclipse, the program runs completely fine. When I click test wrapper in Launch4j (using jdk-15.0.1 as a jre), I see in the log that there is a `NullPointerException` due to `java.net.URL.toString()`.

My program has dependencies on the Spotify API and it also has some Selenium code in it as well. I am not too sure what is causing this problem, since all of the code works perfectly in Eclipse and there is nowhere in my code that attempts to get the string of a null URL.

Here is the error that I see in the log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toString()" because "url" is null
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.SunToolkit.getImageFromHash(SunToolkit.java:653)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.SunToolkit.getImage(SunToolkit.java:689)
    at views.view.initComponents(view.java:419)
    at views.view.<init>(view.java:123)
    at views.view$1.run(view.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: So I was able to fix the problem by creating a new java project and copying and pasting the code in. I am not too sure what the issue was but it works now!

Comment: I suspect it was a problem with an image resource not being in the expected place in the JAR.  However, there is no clear evidence, and since the problem has "gone away" (and you don't know exactly why) this should be closed as Not Reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Today the same thing happened to me, and in my case the problem was that a directory had the first letter in uppercase and in Java I had put it in lowercase.

When I correctly renamed the directory, I exported it again and no longer received the error.